# Error sending message to Mule API from BizTalk

Tags: rest, wcf, mule, biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

I am trying to post a message to Mule service, which is expected to respond with Success or Error Response. When I post a request directly to the Mule API using Postman, it gives a response as 200 with some HTML content. When I am pushing the same request with similar headers from BizTalk send port, I get the following error:

> An error occurred while processing the message, refer to the details section for more information Message ID: {56AF4477-590F-415E-9D70-536692FE637C} Instance ID: {20EEC344-3B1A-474E-ACEB-160CBF616775} Error Description: System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to https://. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Net.Security._SslStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Net.TlsStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Net.Connection.ReadCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult result) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- Server stack trace: at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.End(SendAsyncResult result) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult result) Exception rethrown at [0]: at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult result) at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WcfClient`2.RequestCallback(IAsyncResult result)

This call from the BizTalk interface to Mule API was working fine until yesterday.
I have tried using Fiddler to see the HTTP traffic from the BizTalk server. It shows the handshake with the Mule service, but no further information on headers or the request body.
Please help.

**UPDATE**

When I posted the request directly to the Mule Api from another machine, it gave a proper response. This seems like a network issue, some rules may have been modified to allow traffic from specific servers. Waiting for the network team to confirm.

Comment: What version of BizTalk?  Have you implemented the TLS 1.2 settings in registry?  I suspect that Mule will only accepts TLS 1.2, check that.

Comment: It is 2013 R2, have cumulative updates applied as well. The TLS 1.2 settings are also implemented.

Comment: Yes, that sort of error is indicative of a communications layer issue, I've seen it most commonly with TLS issues.   Have you browsed to the URL endpoint with a browser from the BizTalk Server?  Does that work?

Comment: When I tried to browse the URL in Chrome/IE, it is re-directing to some sign-in page. That explains the HTML response. The service URL needs client-id/secret to give a proper response though, which were given in headers of BizTalk or Postman request.

Comment: The network team confirmed they were redirecting traffic to another URL, which required different authorization. When they reverted their changes, the BizTalk interface was able to push the messages again. Thanks @Dijkgraaf !